# Which Banach spaces are absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

A metric space $X$ is defined to be an  *absolute Lipschitz extensor for compacta* if each Lipschitz map $f:K\to K$ defined on a compact subset $K\subset X$ extends to a Lipschitz map $\bar f: X\to X$.

**Question.** Is each Banach space an absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta?

I admit that the answer to this question is negative. In this case the Question can be refined to

**Problem.** Which Banach spaces are absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta?

**Remark.** The class of absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta includes all absolute Lipschitz retracts, so it includes all Hilbert spaces and all Banach spaces $C_u(M)$ of bounded continuous functions on a metric space  $M$. What about uniformly rotund Banach spaces (are they absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta)? Are the Banach spaces $L_p(\mu)$ absolute Lipschitz extensors for compacta?

Comment: $\ell_2 \oplus C[0,1]$ gives a negative answer to your question. Map almost isometric $\ell_2^n$ subspaces of $C[0,1]$ linearly isometrically onto subspaces of $\ell_2 \oplus\{0\}$ and restrict to the unit ball to get compact domains. If there is a Lipschitz extension with norm $A_n$, there is by Lindenstrauss non linear paper a linear extension $B_n$ with norm $3\|A_n\|$ (or maybe $\|A_n\|$). The norm of $B_n$ must go to infinity at rate at least $n^{1/2}$. Argue that if extensions of contractions always exist, there must be a bound on the Lipschitz constants of the best extensions.

Comment: No time now for a detailed answer, but I imagine what I wrote is enough for you.

Comment: @BillJohnson Thank you for the answer of the Question. You can write it as an answer and then I will accept it. By the way, the existence of the bound for Lipschitz extension (implying from the existence of Lipschitz extensions). Is it written anywhere? I want to cite this result and not prove it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way you can prove that a space $X$ is not an absolute extensor for compacta: Find sequences $(E_n)$ and $(F_n)$ of finite dimensional subspaces of $X$ and a constant $C$ so that for every $n$ there is a linear isomorphism $T_n$ from $E_n$ onto $F_n$ s.t. $\|T_n\|=1$, $\|T_n^{-1}\|\le C$,    each $F_n$ is the range of a projection of norm at most $C$, but the $E_n$ are not uniformly complemented. If the restriction of $T_n $ to the unit ball $B_{E_n}$ of $E_n$ has a $D$ Lipschitz extension from $B_X$ into $X$, then it has a $CD$-Lipschitz extension into $F_n$, and the positively homogenous extension of this mapping    is a $3CD$-Lipschitz extension of $T_n$ to a mapping from $X$ into $F_n$.  By Lindenstrauss' 1964 paper on non linear projections (see the book of Benyamini-Lindenstrauss), there is then a linear extension $S_n:X \to F_n$ with $\|S_n\|\le  3DC$ so that $T_n^{-1}S_n$ is a projection from $X$ onto $E_n$ having norm at most $3DC^2$.  So if such an X is an absolute extensor for compacta, there is no  uniform Lipschitz bound on extensions of non expansive linear mappings from finite dimensional subspaces.

It remains to show that if a space $X$ is  an absolute extensor for compacta,  then there is a uniform bound on extensions of non expansive linear mappings defined on  finite dimensional subspaces. Suppose there is no such uniformity for $X$.  Notice that then if $Y$ is a finite codimensional subspace of $X$, then there also is no uniformity for extensions of non expansive linear mappings defined on unit balls of finite dimensional subspaces  of $Y$   into $X$. Now use the Mazur technique for constructing basic sequences to build a finite dimensional Schauder decomposition $(E_n)$ for some subspace of $X$ and non expansive linear mappings $f_n: E_n \to X$ s.t. any extension of $f_n$ to $X$ has Lipschitz constant at least $n  $. Let $K = \cup_n n^{-1} B_{E_n}$ and define $F:K\to X$ by $f(x) = f_n(x)$ if $x\in n^{-1} E_n$. Then $K$ is compact and $f$ is Lipschitz and $f$ has no Lipschitz extension to $X$.

There are many spaces that contain sequences $(E_n)$ and $(F_n)$ of finite dimensional subspaces  for which there is a constant $C$ so that for every $n$ there is a linear isomorphism $T_n$ from $E_n$ onto $F_n$ s.t. $\|T_n\|=1$, $\|T_n^{-1}\|\le C$,    each $F_n$ is the range of a projection of norm at most $C$, but the $E_n$ are not uniformly complemented. 
If $X$ is $ \ell_p$ or $L_p$, $1\le p \not=2 <\infty$,  then $E_n$ can be taken to be uniformly isomorphic to $\ell_p^n$.  If $X$ is super reflexive (or even just has non trivial type) but does not have type $p$ for some $p<2$, then $E_n$ can be taken to be uniformly isomorphic to $\ell_2^n$. These results are fairly deep, BTW, but well known to researchers in Banach space theory.

Comment: Hi Professor Johnson. I would like to know more about the construction of $E_n$ and $F_n$ in your answer. May i know any reference of it? Thanks.